# Windows Server 2008 cloud backup solution

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-backup

I am looking for a cloud backup solution on Windows Server 2008.
It is a Web server with nearly 250 Gb of data.
I've been using Azure cloud backup, but a problem has appeared recently that when it runs, it causes an extremely high disk usage, and the sites hosted here slow down to a crawl. Is there a somewhat non-intrusive solution that throttles its speed according to disk usage?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft:

Network throttling is not available on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2008 SP2, or Windows 7 (with service packs). The Azure Backup network throttling feature engages Quality of Service (QoS) on the local operating system. Though Azure Backup can protect these operating systems, the version of QoS available on these platforms doesn't work with Azure Backup network throttling. Network throttling can be used on all other supported operating systems.

The bandwidth values begin at 512 kilobits per second (Kbps) and can go up to 1,023 megabytes per second (MBps). You can also designate the start and finish for Work hours, and which days of the week are considered work days. Hours outside of designated work hours are considered non-work hours.

Back up a Windows Server or client to Azure using the Resource Manager deployment model

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-configure-vault